# Multiple snapshots of social network, showing people leaving

Tags: data-request, social-media

Are there any available data sets for social networks, like facebook, where the data is longitudinal (multiple versions over time) and captures the leave (or any similar activity like inactivity, account deactivation, or account permanent deletion)?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be GitHub.  Public events are timestamped and therefore one can observe a user creating an account, any public usage or contribution activity, and if the account was deleted.  Some potential sources would be the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), [GHArchive](https://www.gharchive.org/), and [GHTorrent](http://ghtorrent.org/).